# TWS (Tivoli Workload Scheduler)

Tags: rhel-5

I am trying to install TWS 8.5.1 & DB2 9.1.0.3 (32 bit) on RHEL 5.5 32 bit.
DB2 is installed successfully but when I am trying to install TWS an error is thrown in midway i.e. PAM authentication error ....

I tried :
disabled SELinux,Firewall but still the same error is thrown...

**[3/28/12 8:04:26:288 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: Pam Authentication failed for user: maestro
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:199)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:289 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:290 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:329)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:92)
[3/28/12 8:04:26:291 GMT+05:30] 0000000a SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: Pam Authentication failed for user:**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Authentication failure i.e. you must set a password for the user "maestro" before proceeding ahead with installation.
Else the this will throw pam authentication error that is shown above.